# Draw Floating Layout on Android launcher and other apps screens and managing the life cycle of this layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service, android-windowmanager

I want to make a floating layout appears on all screens of any apps on the phone, and I can make actions on this layout besides other app running beside this layout can receive it's own actions and events

And here is an app which do what I want https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ninja.sms

Here is the approach which I have worked on:
I used WindowManager to draw the layout on and a service to manage this layout.

I used the following library https://github.com/t0mm13b/TouchSoftly  but it has some problems 
1. The layout doesn't receive actions or touch events, the actions goes to the views under the one which drawn by this library. 
2. The layout disappear when the activity which launched the service killed.

So, I have made some customization on it in the following snippet

```
    _layOutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    _layOutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    _layOutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    _layOutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    if (_layOutParams != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() - Got _layOutParams!");
        _layOutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
    } else
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() - _layOutParams is null! :(");


    _hudPageView = _layOutInflater.inflate(R.layout.service_hudpageview, null);
```

The result is that : the layout already drawn and can get touch event but the Home, Back and Recent apps buttons doesn't work or have any effect on any app while the layout appear on the screen.

So still doesn't achieve what I want.

And Here is the source code and repository which I am working on, so u can review my source code 
https://github.com/mmelsabry/FloatingLayout

I know there is another question here [Floating widget / Overlay on Android launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443820/floating-widget-overlay-on-android-launcher)

but it doesn't help

Comment: Find the tutorial at the link [StandOut - Create Floating Apps][1]


  [1]: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531

Comment: try this: it contains all that you need, easy to read.
https://github.com/EatHeat/FloatingExample

Answer (score 0):

Try using TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY instead of TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT.

Comment: Can you explain in detail? This answer is not sufficient