# View in a different window

Tags: java, android, view

I just find a app in the playstore and really liked the view which can be opened every time and in any App . So I asked myself how to do that and searched for some keywords but without success :/ Is there any Tutorial to do sth like that ? Do you guys have a right keyword for it ? I just want to be able to open up my application but also see the background. Its hard to explain so I just insert the link in my post .

It would be awesome if you can help me ! :)

Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ac0eLZE-vQ

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443820/floating-widget-overlay-on-android-launcher

Answer (score 1):

"Floating Calculator" was created using [Tooleap SDK](http://www.tooleap.com) as [stated here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floaters.calculator) -

> **Update:** Following questions from developers, we used an SDK called Tooleap to
>   create the floating UI.

As I [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28342025/4291049), it enables to create floating widgets using regular Activities.