# setAlpha behaving weird

Tags: android, alpha

I have added a view with special params using windowmanager, it overlays the screen and I am trying to change the alpha of this view using a seekbar. I have tried changing the alpha of a button just to test my code, and it works properly, but when I try to change the alpha of the overlay view, it just changes colour to a transparent black (it is normally transparent pink or yellow). I was hoping to change the opacity of the yellow or pink, but it does not seem to work that way. I think it is because of the special params, or the fact that it is added using windowmanager. The `float alpha = intent.getExtras().getFloat("alpha");` is passed down from my main activity and is the progress of my seekbar(max = 100)/100 so it ends up being a value of 0.0 to 1.0. If anybody has any ideas let me know, thanks. Here is the service:

```
`public class DrawOverAppsService extends Service {

    public static final String TAG = "DrawOverAppsService";



    View mOverlayView;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");


        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN|
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        // An alpha value to apply to this entire window.
        // An alpha of 1.0 means fully opaque and 0.0 means fully transparent
        params.alpha = 0.2F;

        // When FLAG_DIM_BEHIND is set, this is the amount of dimming to apply.
        // Range is from 1.0 for completely opaque to 0.0 for no dim.
        params.dimAmount = 0.5F;

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        mOverlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_view, null);

        wm.addView(mOverlayView, params);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (mOverlayView != null) {
            Boolean isBlack = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("black");
            Boolean isPink = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("pink");
            Boolean isOrange = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("orange");
            Boolean isAlpha = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("isAlpha");

            if(isBlack == true) {
                mOverlayView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            }
            if(isPink == true) {
                mOverlayView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3d0d00"));
            }
            if(isOrange == true) {
                mOverlayView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3d2f00"));
            }
            if (isAlpha == true) {
                float alpha = intent.getExtras().getFloat("alpha");

                mOverlayView.getBackground().setAlpha((int)alpha);
                //mOverlayView.setAlpha(intent.getExtras().getFloat("alpha"));

            }

        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.removeView(mOverlayView);


    }
}`
```

Comment: Changing the colour of `mOverlayView` works fine, but changing the alpha does not.

Comment: Take a look at WindowManager's `updateViewLayout()` to set alpha using layout parameters.

Comment: Wow, thank you! That was exactly what I needed. For some reason I also needed to change `intent.putExtra("alpha", alpha.getProgress()/100;);` to `Float alpha2 = alpha.getProgress()/100f;
        intent.putExtra("alpha", alpha2);` I thought they would be the same but I guess not! Thanks for the help.

Comment: `alpha.getProgress()` is an int so int/int rounds down toward zero. `alpha.getProgress()/100` will either be zero (if `getProgress()` < 100) or 1 if (`getProgress()` == 100).

Comment: @Cheticamp Sorry to ask you for so much help, but if you don't mind can you check out my new question? Thanks so much for the help so far. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856939/why-isnt-my-alarm-going-off-android)

Answer (score 0):

Open()

```
mOverlayView .animate().scaleX(1.0f).scaleY(1.0f).setDuration(200)
                .start();
        mOverlayView .setAlpha(0.5f);
```

Close()

```
mOverlayView .animate().scaleX(0f).scaleY(0f).setDuration(200).start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have solved it a different way but I will upvote this for trying to help me.